# Passing off strings to "alphabet" that contains specific characters for lexical analysis

Tags: python-3.x, token, lexical-analysis, dfa

In python, I want to know how I can pass off the strings that checks:

> 1. if something contains only alphanumeric characters
> 2. if something contains only digits
> 3. if something contains neither alphanumeric characters nor digits.

I am having a hard time figuring out the syntax and I specifically need strings like these instead of using built-in functions for lexical analysis. The following will clear the idea of what I'am trying to do:

```
alphanumeric=r'[a-zA-Z]+'
digit=r'[0-9]'
other=r'![a-zA-Z_0-9]'
alphabet = {alphanumeric ,digit,other}
```

This alphabet along with other DFA attributes will be fed into the dfa object's function run_with_input_list() with some user defined string. The dfa class structure is below:

```
class DFA:
    current_state = None

    def __init__(self, states, alphabet, transition_function, start_state, accept_states):  #5-tupple
        self.states = states
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.transition_function = transition_function
        self.start_state = start_state
        self.accept_states = accept_states
        self.current_state = start_state
        return

    def transition_to_state_with_input(self, input_value):
        if ((self.current_state, input_value) not in self.transition_function.keys()):
            self.current_state = None
            return
        self.current_state = self.transition_function[(self.current_state, input_value)]
        return

    def in_accept_state(self):
        if self.current_state in self.accept_states:
            print("String Accepted")
        else:
            print("String Rejected")

    def go_to_initial_state(self):
        self.current_state = self.start_state
        return

    def run_with_input_list(self, input_list):
        self.go_to_initial_state()
        for inp in input_list:
            self.transition_to_state_with_input(inp)
            continue
        return self.in_accept_state()

    pass

    def validity(self,input_list):   #checking whether the input string is valid
        for a in input_list:
            if a in self.alphabet:
                continue
            else:
                print("Invalid String")
                return 0
        return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite understand what "passing off" means, but these are the methods you can use :

1) Check if it contains only alphabets

```
print("abcd".isalpha()) #True
print("abcd123".isalpha()) #False
print("123".isalpha()) #False
```

2) Check if it contains only numbers

```
print("123".isnumeric()) #True
print("abcd".isnumeric()) #False
print("abcd123".isnumeric()) #False
```

3) Check if it contains only alphabets / numbers

```
print("abc123".isalnum()) #True
print("abc???".isalnum()) #False
```

Comment: actually, I need to use specifically, the strings I specified like [A-Za-z].

Comment: @MujtabaFaizi which is taken care of by `isalpha`

Answer (score 0):

Python regular expressions already have special characters for this - digit has `\d` alphanumeric has `\w`, non-alphanumeric character has `\W`.

References: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

Python provides standard helpers for such operation, look at this example:

```
def what_is(s):
    is_num = s.isnumeric()
    is_alpha = s.isalpha()
    is_other = not is_num and not is_alpha
    return is_num, is_alpha, is_other


def main():
    alpha = "Ciao"
    num = "0102"
    other = "£*+]"
    print(what_is(alpha))
    print(what_is(num))
    print(what_is(other))
```

Comment: actually, I need to use specifically, the strings I specified like [A-Za-z].